# How to access firebase result outside then method React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i am new to react and firebase.

*PROBLEM:*

I am trying to access a variable which returns true when it successfully gets the result, it is working inside .then method, but outside then method  cannot get the result (isStudent variable).
I
any suggestions, hints would be helpful.

```
     const Routes = props => {
                  if (props.user) {
                     let isStudent=false;

                    const uid = props.user.uid;

                    firebase
                      .database()
                      .ref(`student/${uid}`)
                      .once("value")
                      .then(snapshot => {
                        if (snapshot.val().role === "student") {
                          console.log(snapshot.val());
                            isStudent=true
                        }
                      });

                    console.log(isStudent); //false
//i am getting the default value, if i remove that i get undefined

                  return (
                    <MainLayout>
                      <Switch>

                <StudentPublicRoute
                          {...props}
                          exact
                          restricted={true}
                          path="/student/login"
                          component={StudentLogin}
                        />
                        {isStudent&& <StudentPrivateRoute
                          {...props}
                          path="/student/studentdashboard"
                          exact
                          component={StudentDash}
                        />}
                 </Switch>
                    </MainLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `once` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which means that your function will run asynchronous, so the function `console.log` runs before you get the response from firebase.

In your case you will need to keep the value of isStudent in the [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

The result will be something like this:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isStudent: false};
  }
  ...

  firebase
  .database()
  .ref(`student/${uid}`)
  .once("value")
  .then(snapshot => {
  if (snapshot.val().role === "student") {
      this.setState({
        isStudent: true
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: And the call should  be made outside render(). He should do it inside componentDidMount() or componentDidUpdate()

Comment: thanks...:) is there any way to do the same with stateless components?

Comment: You’ll need to wrap the database access logic in a parent component that will render your current component, passing the prop isStudent.

Answer (score 0):

This is because console.log(isStudent) executes before isStudent=true.

This will always be the case since the call to firebase takes some time.  Consider also using a class component rather than a function component and use some framework like redux/saga or redux/thump for asynchronous calls like this.

Maybe you could try with await/async, it may work.

Your code, as is, will never work.

Comment: yeah, thanks :) .. is there any possible way that i can modify the same stateless component, because my below components are dependent on ...props

Comment: function components are the most basic ones. No state, no lifecycle hooks, only props. If you want to achieve that without a class component, you will have the containing component perform the call, given the parent component also a function component.

Consider reviewing your design and I strongly recommend using redux/saga for asynchrnonous calls.